# c# run windows form from console and run both of them

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, multiple-instances

There is a console application that simulates router functionality (packet swithcing and so on). I made a simple Windows Form that should show how much each router's socket is used. Each socket has different capacity and each Form "connected" to socket should show how much capacity there is still available.

My code so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        //get number of router's sockets
        args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        int socketnumber = Convert.ToInt32(args[2]);
        //get sockets' capacity
        int[] array = new int[socketnumber];
        for (int i = 0; i < socketnumber; i++)
        {
            array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(args[3 + i]);
        }
```

Now, LRM is a WinForm that shows each socket's (or, more accurately, link's attached to socket) status, so I initialize it and give it parameters.

```
            LRM[] lrm = new LRM[socketnumber];

            for (int i = 0; i < socketnumber; i++)
            {
                lrm[i] = new LRM();
                lrm[i].Show();
                a++;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < socketnumber; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
                lrm[i].capacity = array[i];
                lrm[i].available = array[i];
                lrm[i].WriteCapacity(lrm[i].capacity);
                lrm[i].WriteAvailable(lrm[i].available);
            }
```

WriteCapacity and WriteAvailable are methods that are invoked by router to update values on LRM, like that:

```
    public void WriteAvailable(int ava)
    {
    MethodInvoker mi = delegate ()
       {
        textBox2.Text = ava.ToString();
       };
    Invoke(mi);
    }
```

Now, current problems I have:

1) Running multiple windows forms from console AND maintaining their functionality (all of them simultaneously), when number of windows forms varies (is set by command line argument)

2) Updating LRM values. When using show() method it just displays the form, it does not give it any values, and soon after form stops to respond, giving windows error. When using Application.Run() method, one form runs nicely, but neither other LRMs nor router's console works.

Comment: Use single form and a control like `DataGridView` or `ListView` to display the sockets info.

Answer (score -1):

I appreciate Alexander Petrov's answer, but I found a way to solve my problem.

I tried Thread approach. First I made most of my variables static:

```
    static int[] array;
    static LRM[] lrm;
    static int port;
```

then I made method that will be acting as thread starting method

```
    private static void startLRM(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        lrm[i].Text = "LRM R" + ((port / 10) - 120).ToString() + " S" + a.ToString();
        a++;

        Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
        lrm[i].capacity = array[i];
        lrm[i].available = array[i];
        lrm[i].WriteCapacity(lrm[i].capacity);
        lrm[i].WriteAvailable(lrm[i].available);
        lrm[i].ShowDialog();
    }
```

Then, in Main() method, I allocated memory for link resource managers,and in for loop I made as many LRMs as were needed.

```
        lrm = new LRM[socketnumber];

        for (int i = 0; i < socketnumber; i++)
        {
        lrm[i] = new LRM();
        Thread thread = new Thread(() => startLRM(i));
        thread.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(150);
        }
```

Sleeping was actually necessary, because for unknown reasons I got errors when it was not there.

Finally, I get what I needed - a console application, which shows what is happening, and few windows forms that shows in nice manner some values.